# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint after restarting Docker

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

I got a `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` after I quit and start my application via docker compose.

I am using a postgresql database while the business logic is implemented with Spring. For OR-Mapping I use Hibernate and the id is generated via `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` which maps to sequence in postgresql. It seems like the sequence is regenerated after rebooting the application i.e. the SEQUENCE will start from 1 after restart i.e. when you add two entities to the database and restart the app the first two inserts will fail.

Any suggestions? I am stuck

Comment: Do you let hibernate (recreate) your schema while updating?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.